# Firefox will not update

Tags: updates, firefox, mozilla

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit and the version of Firefox that comes with this version of Ubuntu. I recently went to a website and got a notification that my version of Firefox was no longer supported. I was not aware that Firefox was not being updated as I update regularly. I tried updating from the command line as well as using the Ubuntu Software Updater but neither of these work and my Firefox version is still stuck. I have researched online and have tried adding the Firefox security PPA as well and installed that but when I launch Firefox it is still the same old version that opens.

Comment: What version of Firefox do you actually use?

Comment: What message is returned when you try to update it from command line? And/or what do you see when you try it from the software center?

Comment: Firefox in 14.04 is at ver. 38, quite doubtful that any website would call it " not supported". Maybe take a closer look at what your issue is or post a link to this website.

Comment: Maybe it's got to do with "Flash"? Some sites want the latest-n-greatest version available by default with Google Chrome.

Comment: I think it's just an ad. What's the site?

Comment: The version is showing as 38.0 in the About Firefox menu and I get the error on Gmail as well as shapeoftheweb.mozilla.org. When I try to update it does not show me that an update is available

Answer (score 3):

I eventually tracked down the issue to a plugin I had installed a while back that allows you to modify the header information to look like your using a different OS and browser so the sites I visited were thinking I was on Windows and using an older version of Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 38 is the latest version. I'm pretty sure, if it's a ribbon at the top, or a box in the site, that is an ad. Ignore it.

Comment: I am running version 38 so if that's the case then I am running the latest version but logging into my Gmail and also shapeoftheweb.mozilla.org tells me I need to update

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Gmail screenshot is here - http://tristanagregg.net/images/gmail.jpg

For the Mozilla screen, I cannot see the text but I think it's safe to assume its the same issue since it doesn't allow me to view the page, there is an exclamation symbol and it gives me a link to download the latest version of Firefox
http://tristanagregg.net/images/mozilla.jpg

Comment: That doesn't look real. Screenshot your add-ons list.

Comment: http://tristanagregg.net/images/extensions.jpg

http://tristanagregg.net/images/plugins.jpg

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's the `Ubuntu Firefox Modifications` plugin.